# Can't find proper way to handle authentication in NextJs with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup an api with some authenticated path.

I currently made the following :

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';
import { auth } from 'firebase-admin';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const authenticated = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    const session = request.cookies.get('session')?.value || '';

    if (!session) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: 'shared.api.error.unauthorized' },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    const decodedClaims = await auth().verifySessionCookie(session, true);

    if (!decodedClaims) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: 'shared.api.error.unauthorized' },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch (error) {
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: 'shared.api.error.internalError' },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};
```

Which I call as follow

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';

import { authenticated } from '~workspace/lib/common/auth';

import { intlConfig } from './next.intl.config';

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware(intlConfig);
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (
    request.nextUrl.pathname === '/' ||
    /^(?!.*\/api|_next|_vercel|.*\..*).*$/.test(request.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return intlMiddleware(request);
  }

  if (/^\/api\/.*$/.test(request.nextUrl.pathname)) {
    return authenticated(request);
  }

  NextResponse.next();
}
```

Sadly this do not work as I am using `firebase-admin` and it complain about the component beeing used in client side.

> One of these is marked as a client entry with "use client":

So I tried to remove the firebase part and kept that code under a routing `/login` and kept just

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';
import { auth } from 'firebase-admin';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const authenticated = async (request: NextRequest) => {
  try {
    const session = request.cookies.get('session')?.value || '';

    if (!session) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: 'shared.api.error.unauthorized' },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

  const responseAPI = await fetch(`${request.nextUrl.origin}/api/auth`, {
    headers: {
      Cookie: `session=${session?.value}`,
    },
  });

  if (responseAPI.status !== 200) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: 'shared.api.error.unauthorized' },
      { status: 401}
    );
  }

    return NextResponse.next();
  } catch (error) {
    Sentry.captureException(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: 'shared.api.error.internalError' },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};
```

Now the new error is

> node:stream
> Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:stream" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
> Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
> You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.

So I am very lost on how to do something as simple as checking a route.

I do not want to add code on every single route to check if user is authenticated, I would like something that I can setup once and configure.